# Formula Field exception:The Tab formula is not valid

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting the exception  Tab Formula for tab, t4 is invalid. Formula = [t2]+[t1]: Tag Label must be unique.

I have checkbox, a fundname and amount to invest in fund.
if user check the checkbox he need to fill the amount in amount box and there is total amount calculated based on the no of amount box has amount entered.

Evertything is working fine but only issue is with formula field. it is throwing an exception formula is invalid.

below is what I am using for showing the calculation:

```
 var fullAnchor4 = new Tab
      {
          Type = TabTypeCode.Custom,
          CustomTabType = CustomTabType.Formula,
          CustomTabTypeSpecified = true,
          AnchorTabItem =
              new AnchorTab
              {
                  AnchorTabString = "tbx4_1_text",

                  XOffset = -10,
                  YOffset = -5

              },
          CustomTabWidth = 100,
          CustomTabWidthSpecified = true,
          Formula = "<formula>[t2]+[t1]</formula>"

      };
      fullAnchor4.DocumentID = "1";
      fullAnchor4.PageNumber = "1";
      fullAnchor4.RecipientID = "1";
      fullAnchor4.TabLabel = "t4";
      fullAnchor4.RoundDecimalPlaces = 2;
      runningList.Add(fullAnchor4);
```

is there something I am doing wrong?

EDIT--

Attached the raw request. removed sensitive info

http://wikisend.com/download/218254/RawRequest 1.txt

Comment: Very hard to diagnose by looking at the source code, please post the raw request body that this actually creates.  You can use a tool like Fiddler to capture it.

Comment: below is the rwa request that is getting generated http://wikisend.com/download/417196/RawRequest.txt]RawRequest.txt

Comment: This is the request after making change Formula = "[t2]+[t1]"  http://wikisend.com/download/417196/RawRequest.txt]RawRequest1.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per DocuSign's documentation, Formula Fields cannot be Anchored (link below). Unsure if this is still true today. Also, I noticed in your document you have the Formula Field's Anchor String listed twice. You have it also listed where an email address would be placed "Email Address: tbx4_1_text". Once I removed that duplicate string from the document the call was successful and the Formula Field appears to be calculating correctly.

https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-user-guide/advanced-sending/using-the-calculated-fields-feature

Answer (score 1):

Your Formula value should not have XML tags in it.  Your resulting API request looks like this:

```
<Formula>&lt;formula&gt;[t2]+[t1]&lt;/formula&gt;</Formula>
```

You should use something like this:

```
Formula = "[t2]+[t1]"
```

The resulting XML will end up like this:

```
<Formula>[tw]+[t1]</Formula>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, I tried using Formula = "[t2]+[t1]" but still same issue is coming.

Comment: I'm curious, I noticed that you are not setting an initial value for `t1` and `t2`,  so maybe the system is trying to add two undefined numbers?  What happens if you set an initial value of 0 for your fields?